# Headers/footers not showing (fancyhdr)

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a slight problem. When I use the `fancyhdr` package, no headers/footers are published. I'm not sure why

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{Fig/}}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\title{{The Study of Everything}\\
{\large University of Something}}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{rom}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\input{tex/introduction}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\input{tex/Chapter2}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\input{tex/Chapter3}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\input{tex/Chapter4}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\input{tex/conclusion}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\input{tex/acknowledgement}\newpage\cleardoublepage
%\bibliography{bib/Literature}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

I've only done the Introduction and Chapter 2... here is what they look like

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
I was motivated to write a Phd thesis because I did not want to work directly after finishing my studies.
\section{Organization}
This thesis is organized as follows, ...

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Literature Review}

I love literature reviews because it show me how little I know...
```

Comment: There are no headers on the page where the chapter title is displayed. Try adding some more text to fill a page and the heading will be displayed on the next one.